# SQL order by two columns like source, target sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, sql-order-by

I have my table like this:

```
ID  SOURCE  TARGET
1      9      8
2      0      7
3      5      4
4      4      9
5      7      5
```

So, how can I order this to make like:

```
ID  SOURCE  TARGET
2      0      7
5      7      5
3      5      4
4      4      9
1      9      8
```

Starting with '0' ordering by target, and the next source columns...

```
drop table if exists test;
create table  test(id integer, source integer, target integer);

DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_ts;

CREATE INDEX idx_ts
  ON test
  USING btree
  (source);

DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.idx_tt;

CREATE INDEX idx_tt
  ON test
  USING btree
  (target);


insert into  test values(1, 9, 8);
insert into  test values(2, 0, 7);
insert into  test values(3, 5, 4);
insert into  test values(4, 4, 9);
insert into  test values(5, 7, 5);
```

That's my sample table.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with SQL.

Comment: What's the exact logic behind this sorting order?

Comment: @Johan: it **is** possible with [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides)

Comment: Interesting @a_horse_with_no_name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a recursive query that builds up the tree. In order to get the order of the hierarchy right, you need to count know the "level" of each row.

```
with recursive targets as (
  select id, source, target, 1 as level
  from omar
  where source = 0
  union all
  select c.id, c.source, c.target, p.level + 1
  from omar c 
    join targets p on c.source = p.target
)
select id, source, target
from targets
order by level;
```

As your hierarchy is "flat", it is enough to just calculate the level which is essentially the distance from the starting point.

For more details on recursive queries [check out the tutorial in the Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: It's Perfect! Thanks.